# aforge image comparison with UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, aforge, image-comparison

I'm using portable.aforge.imaging for image comparison on a UWP project. The method ProcessImage requires Bitmap type as arguments. I'm using System.Drawing to access Bitmap class, but i'm getting errors when i try to instantiate: "Bitmap does not contains a constructor that takes 1 argument"

Does regular Bitmap class is available on UWP? if yes, what am i doing wrong? if not, what alternatives do i have to use the aforge's ProcessImage for comparison?

```
 private void TestAForge()
    {

        ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0);

        Bitmap image, template;

        //fetch Bitmaps

        image = new Bitmap("MyDir/myImage.jpg");
        template = new Bitmap("MyDir/myImage.jpg");

        // compare two images
        TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(image, template);
        // check similarity level
        TextBlock.Text = "" + matchings[0].Similarity;
        if (matchings[0].Similarity > 0.95)
        {

            // do something with quite similar images
        }
    }
```

Comment: This `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is not from .NET Framework, but comes with `portable.aforge.imaging` (in Shim.Drawing). Looking at its code, it seems that you can only create an instance by casting from WriteableBitmap by `public static explicit operator Bitmap(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap)`. Or possibly create an `Image` instance by `Image.FromStream()` and cast it to Bitmap (not sure if that works).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is available via the *Shim.Drawing* assembly for *AForge* on the *Universal Windows Platform*.

As *Clemens* suggests, you need to cast from a `WriteableBitmap` to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, apply the *AForge* imaging operations on the `Bitmap` and finally cast back to `WriteableBitmap` (or `BitmapSource` or `ImageSource`).

An example of where this workflow is implemented can be found in the *Corner.SURF.Windows* sample in the [accord-samples](https://github.com/cureos/accord-samples) repository, in the file [MainPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/cureos/accord-samples/blob/master/Corners.SURF.Windows/MainPage.xaml.cs).